# oAuth manage_pages scope is requested, but Manage your Pages permission request missing

Tags: oauth, permissions, facebook-page

I have working code to request the user to grant manage_pages permission to my app during the oAuth process.  This code has been in place for many months and has not changed.  When I test the steps, on the "Your App Name Here" would like to request permission to:  popup, I clearly see the "Manage your Pages" permission request.

I have a client who follows the exact same steps I do, (I sent a doc with screen shots and did a WebEx to watch), when she gets to the page that requests specific permissions, the "Manage your Pages" permission is not listed.

Does anyone have an idea why that permission would be missing for one Facebook account and not another?

Comment: What permissions are granted to the access token? Check with a call to /me/permissions - they may already have granted that permission

Comment: We have tested with a new page, so there were no pre-existing permissions.  We created a brand new page, tied it to a new email address for the account, and then started the oAuth process for my app.  The client logs into her new page and enters credentials.  Then Facebook displays the page asking for specific permissions.  I have scope specified as Manage Your Pages, Post on your behalf, and Access your data any time.  In this user's case, the "Manage your pages" section is missing.

Comment: You're still missing some information here - do you have a sample of the code which is directing to the auth dialog but not including manage pages on the second page?